# Advanced Custom Fields in Functions.php (Wordpress)

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I am trying to pull an Advanced Custom Field in my Functions.php of my child theme and it's not working. Any ideas?

```
add_action('init', 'my_function_to_add_field_groups');
function my_function_to_add_field_groups() {
  $section_name = get_field('section_name');

  print "the $section_name";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A couple things i'm seeing without having any more context then what's given:

1. Is the custom field you're trying to access one that does not require specifying the 'post_id' ? If it does require 'post_id', for debugging at least i would give adding the 'post_id' as a parameter: `get_field('field_name', {Your Post ID});`
2. When you define `print "the $section_name";` PHP is assuming that your variable is part of the string and not meant to be concatenated. Can you try a quick concatenation of the string+variable like: `print "the ".$section_name;` ?

Comment: I tried both your suggestions and the same result. Maybe some context will help I'm build a site in Wordpress w Divi. I want to change menus per section. So I created a ACF for Sections. I want to be able read the Section from functions.php so I can change the menu on the fly.

Comment: Is this a custom post type you're trying to access the field ````section_name```` of?